# Mach-Zehnder interferometer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interferometry

I assume there are 2 kinds of Mach-Zehnder interferometers: real-world devices which detect for example impurities in gases and quantum devices used mainly in thought experiments, though I am sure real experiments were also done somewhere. I wonder how the two are related, for example precision requirements. How real is to construct a quantum MZI?

Comment: They are already in widespread use in quantum optics labs (including $U(n)$ interferometers).

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of quantum interferometers in an MZ configuration, here are two based on the coherent manipulation of atoms by light

[Matterwave analog to a fibre gyroscope](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.12461)

[Simultaneous Dual-Species Matter-Wave Accelerometer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2734)